# GridView 3 columns 1 or 2 items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I have a layout that is based on a 3 column GridView. The problem now is that my number of items isn't divisible by 3 so there will always be 1 or 2 items at the last row.

Normally it will look like that:

[image]

What i want to do is to place all excess items to be placed in a new order. Just like that:

[image]

Or with one excess item in the center of the column.

So my question is: Is it possible to do this in a GridView? If it is, how can I do this?

Thanks a lot to every answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is how GridView layour it's child views.

You might want to switch using [Dashboard layout](https://gist.github.com/romannurik/882650) or even better- recycle view with custom GridLayoutManager that you set the span size for you last items.

Comment: I made a big progress with my app. But there still is this little problem stated before. Now I'm working with a RecyclerView and a GridLayoutManager. But do not really know how I can set the span size for only the last two items.

I appreciate all help :)